# I have ran .sql file through liquibase, made some changes to the file and now checksum validation fails

Tags: sql, oracle, liquibase

The SQL script was:

```
ALTER TABLE ENGINE ADD IS_READY NUMBER(1,0);
COMMENT ON COLUMN ENGINE.IS_READY IS 'Is ready?';
```

I have ran the file on the database. The change to the database was made.

Now I have changed the first line of the script to:

```
ALTER TABLE ENGINE ADD IS_READY NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0;
```

Want to run the new script to update the database, but I get an error:

```
Error setting up or running Liquibase: Validation Failed:
[ERROR]      1 change sets check sum
[ERROR]      src/main/resources/liquibase/1.x/db.changelog.xml::script_executed::xxx.xxx was: 7:44a92c557ec5c4170cdab05ec49dd164 but is now: 7:3d3048f7178ed52b1816b81b170a515d
```

How to deal with that? A rollback? Then run the new script?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the changelog XML. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `liquibase` version > 3.5.0 you can add

`--validCheckSum: your-check-sum`